# How to check if html select option was not selected by user - php

Tags: php, html

I have a contact form where I'm trying to catch if the user does not select an option "OR" forgets to select one from the select drop down list and is still set to the first option "Choose Option". In this case it should give the user an Alert "Please select option" which is called by `flash('contact');`.

But when I try to do `if` statements in the controller.php to check this, it is not giving the Alert error - rather is giving me my "Message Submitted(also `flash('contact');`)". And then I check my mailing test account and it is sending the email but shouldn't.

I have other `if` statements that check the inputs `if(empty)` and proper email type `if(!filter_var)` that are working, but I cannot figure out what I'm doing with the `if` to validate this.

Yes done some research as well. I also have few more options - just tried limiting the amount of code that wasn't necessary.

**contactus.php**

```
flash('contact');

<form method="post" action="./controllers/Contacts.php" class="messageForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="contact">
    <input type="text" name="yourName" onclick="showName()" placeholder="YOUR NAME">
    <input type="text" name="yourEmail" onclick="showEmail()" onchange="showEmailAgain()" placeholder="EMAIL">
    <select name="contactOptions">
        <option value="Default" disabled selected>Choose Option</option>
        <option value="Account Help">Account Help</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
    <textarea id="yourMessage" type="text" name="yourMessage" onclick="showText()" placeholder="YOUR MESSAGE"></textarea>
</form>
```

**./controllers/Contacts.php**

```
 class Contacts {
    public function sendMessage() {
      //Sanitize POST Data
      $_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

      //Grab info from user
      $data = ['yourName' => trim($_POST['yourName']),
       'yourEmail' => trim($_POST['yourEmail']), 
       'contactOptions' => trim($_POST['contactOptions']), 
       'yourMessage' => trim($_POST['yourMessage'])];

      //Have tried 

      //if (isset($_POST['contactOptions'] == "Default")) {
      //  flash();
      //  redirect();
      //}          
      //if ($_POST['contactOptions'] == "Default")) {
      //  flash();
      //  redirect();
      //} 
      //if ("Default") {
      //  flash();
      //  redirect();
      //}                   
     


      //this "if" checks what option user selected that gets sent with 
      //email, is separate from my issue. There are some $this->mails before this if
      if (isset(_POST['submit'])) {                 
        $selected = $_POST['contactOptions'];
        $this->mail->Subject = $selected;
      }

      $this->mail->Body = $subjectMessage;          
      $this->mail->send();

      flash("contact", "Message Submitted", 'form-message form-message-green');
      redirect("../contactus.php");
    }
 }

$init = new Contacts;

//Ensure that user is sending a post request
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    switch ($_POST['type']) {
        case 'contact':
            $init->sendMessage();
            break;
        default:
        redirect("../index.php");
    }
}else{
    redirect("../index.php");
}
```

Comment: You can use `isset()` or `empty()` in PHP to check the $_POST values. You can use `required` in the HTML to do some client-side validation. It's not clear exactly what you tried, because you didn't show your attempt, so we can't really tell you what you might have done wrong. Please provide a [mre] of the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson updated with a few "if" examples I have tried and some clarification. And also thought what I supplied was necessary for explanation, thanks.

Comment: Thanks.  None of those seems quite right. `if (isset($_POST['contactOptions'])` would likely make sense (I don't think the "Default" value will actually be submitted ever, because it's disabled). But flash and then redirect makes no sense - you can either output something, or you can redirect (because if you redirect, then the browser will ignore whatever you output!). And you need to set a flag to say if the data is all validated or not, and then use that in an `if` to determine whether to continue sending the email or not...

Comment: ... Right now your code would show a message but then just carry on sending the email regardless - showing a message doesn't, by itself, change the status or the path the code takes. (Although if your `redirect()` function contains an `exit` or `die` command then that would cover it, but we don't know about that because you didn't share it...see what I mean now about providing a [mre]?)

Comment: @ADyson AH! ok so when I remove the "disabled selected" from the option with `value="Default"` and use the `if (isset($_POST['contactOptions'])`, run the form with default option selected it does what I want. But I don't want the user to be able to select that option "Default" and that's now what that does. I felt that originally this `if (isset($_POST['contactOptions'])` should've worked then I fell down the rabbit hole. They're another way you suggest getting this to work?

Comment: @ADyson BTW the `flash()` and `redirect` call a function from another file that has an `exit()` on them and that's what is making my error alert messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Just replace the code with this code. Your issue will be solved.  

<?php
    public function sendMessage() {
          //Sanitize POST Data
        $_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    
        //Grab info from user
        $data = ['yourName' => trim($_POST['yourName']),
           'yourEmail' => trim($_POST['yourEmail']), 
           'contactOptions' => trim($_POST['contactOptions']), 
           'yourMessage' => trim($_POST['yourMessage'])];
    
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {                    
            $selected = $_POST['contactOptions'];
            if($selected == 'Default'){
                 flash("contact", "Select Contact option First", 'form-message form-message-red');
                redirect("../contactus.php");
            }
            $this->mail->Subject = $selected;
        }
    
          $this->mail->Body = $subjectMessage;          
          $this->mail->send();
    
          flash("contact", "Message Submitted", 'form-message form-message-green');
          redirect("../contactus.php");
        }
     }
```

Comment: OMG! Yes thank you very much it works. I had wrote after posting on here 'elseif ($_POST['contactOptions'] == "Default") {flash("contact", "Please select option"); redirect("../contactus.php");}'.

Answer (score 0):

Change value Default to empty('') for Choose Option.
When you are submitting the form the field contactOptions is submitted with the value Default which is why the form is submitted sucessfully.

Additionally, you can validate your form on client side as well before sending it to the server,

Comment: I updated original code, also so I tried to changed value="Default" to value=" empty('')" and if (empty('')) { flash; redirect; }, think this was what you meant, It does give me the correct error message alert "Please select option", but once I do select option to something other then the default it gives me the same error, although I selected an option. But good news is it does stop it from sending the message to mail.

Comment: can you share the updated code? @09jesses